# Notificações Toast c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone, microsoft-azure, push-notification, windows-10

Olá, Como posso usar o Azure para notificar o usuário que tem novos conteúdos no aplicativo? Estou criando um projeto em `c#` para `Windows 10`. Obrigado desde já.

Answer (score 3):

Você deve utilizar o serviço de [Azure Notification Hub](https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/documentation/services/notification-hubs/).

Envie notificações por push para qualquer plataforma e de qualquer back-end

- Alcance todas as principais plataformas: iOS, Android, Windows, Kindle, Baidu
  Use qualquer back-end: na nuvem ou local
- Difunda rapidamente por push para milhões de dispositivos móveis com uma única chamada à API
- Personalize notificações por push por usuário, idioma e localização
- Defina e notifique segmentos de usuários de maneira dinâmica
- Dimensione para milhões de dispositivos móveis instantaneamente

Para disparar a notificação do back-end:

```
var hub = NotificationHubClient
            .CreateClientFromConnectionString("Endpoint=sb://NOME_DO_SEU_APP.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature;SharedAccessKey=CHAVE_DO_SEU_APP",
            "NOME_DO_SEU_APP");

var toast = @"<toast><visual><binding template=""ToastText01""><text id=""1"">Bem vindos ao VSSummit 2015</text></binding></visual></toast>";

var toastWithImage = @"<toast><visual><binding template=""ToastImageAndText01""><image id=""1"" src=""https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/metro-ui-icon-set/512/Visual_Studio_2012.png"" /><text id=""1"">Bem vindos ao VSSummit15!</text></binding></visual></toast>";

hub.SendWindowsNativeNotificationAsync(toast).Wait();
```

Existem outros modelos/*templates* de notificação como, mensagem simples, com ou sem imagem, com ou sem título, com contadores, etc. Veja aqui outros [modelos de *toast notifications*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dn530748.aspx).

E para fazer seu app receber as notificações:

```
private async void InitNotificationHubAsync()
{
    var channel = await PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync();

    var hub = new NotificationHub("NOME_DO_SEU_APP", "Endpoint=sb://NOME_DO_SEU_APP.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=DefaultListenSharedAccessSignature;SharedAccessKey=CHAVE_COMPARTILHADA_DO_SEU_APP");

    await hub.RegisterNativeAsync(channel.Uri);
}
```

No [meu repositório do GitHub](https://github.com/thiagolunardi) possui um exemplo de como consumir o serviço:

[Exemplo de Azure Notification Hub](https://github.com/thiagolunardi/AzureNotificationHub).

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Thiago :D

Comment: Segui o tutorial à risca. Em modo de debug, funciona tudo perfeito. Depois envio o app para a loja, baixo e o abro. Neste momento ele fecha sem explicações. Já fiz o teste e se remover o codigo, o app volta a funcionar corretamente. Alguma dica?

Comment: Bom, não tem muito o que dizer. Vc só precisa de um jeito de pegar a exception que está ocorrendo e enviar para vc. Existem alguns tutos na web explicando - não tenho nenhum para recomendar. Tente rodar em modo RELEASE no seu aparelho, veja se muda algo. Se não resolver, implemente Azure Application Insights, ele pode pegar alguns comportamentos do app.

Comment: @Leandrolap, se concordar, pode marcar a resposta como a ideal, por gentileza? :)

Comment: o azure notifications hub serve pra mandar push notifications para uma aplicação web pwa? no caso seria em angular